# DateTimeField is not defined error in django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I want to delete the videos from my models whose age is more than one day.

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import urllib
from django.core.files import File 
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
import os
class video(models.Model):
    video_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    video_link = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    video_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to = '',blank = True)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank = True)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    def cache(self):
        if self.image_url and not self.video_thumbnail:
            result = urllib.urlretrieve(self.image_url)
            self.video_thumbnail.save(
                    os.path.basename(self.image_url),
                    File(open(result[0]))
                    )
            self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.video_title + "," + self.video_link + "," + str(self.upload_date)
```

In the shell, I do a query to delete the videos whose age is more than a day as follows:

```
video.objects.filter((datetime.datetime.now() - (upload_date)).total_hours > 24)
```

But I get the following error:

```
In [6]: video.objects.filter((datetime.datetime.now() - (upload_date)).total_hours > 24)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0c1ffc162513> in <module>()
----> 1 video.objects.filter((datetime.datetime.now() - (upload_date)).total_hours > 24)

NameError: name 'upload_date' is not defined
```

Why I am getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is backwards. You can't pass `datetime.datetime.now()` as the first parameter; that's for a field name to compare. You need to reverse the query so that you ask for all Videos whose upload_date is before now minus 24 hours:

```
target_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
video.objects.filter(upload_date__lte=target_time)
```